# Is it ok to refference proxy in another proxy?

Tags: actionscript-3, design-patterns, robotlegs

I just wonder if there are no catches while refferencing a proxy in a proxy. For example in **ProxyA**:

```
[Inject]
private var _proxyB:ProxyB;
```

Answer (score 0):

can you provide more detail and situation Why there is need of referencing a proxy into other Proxy because intent of using proxy is to control the object reference.